# Objective c how to detect an object from camera inside a layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uiviewcontroller, camera

Hello i created a viewController with camera frame that have an over layout of card and leg(looks like an outline of card and leg).

what i need to do from there is to enable "take picture" button only if there is a some objects inside the layouts.

i'm using objective c and supporting ios 9+.
thx for the help

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that can be done out of the box now. You will need some extern library like OpenCV to detect features in your image and be able to detect it.

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html

OpenCV has an iOS project with the lib already but you will have to spend some learning how it works.